# Как сделать такую прокрутку?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать такую прокрутку на сайте, чтобы изображение меняло свои координаты по мере движения прокрутки вверх или вниз?
Примеры прокрутки:
http://www.landingpage.bz/ - движение самолета вверх при прокрутке сайта вниз.
http://www.imstartup.ru/ - первое изображение и изображение с девушкой (ниже)

Answer (score 1):

само явление называется параллакс.

Есть масса готовых решений, например: http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Answer (score 1):

мне больше всего понравилось использовать библиотеку [scrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr)